# Printing UTF8 in Perl?

Tags: perl, unicode

Why does adding the `use utf8` pragma produce garbled output (see below) versus when I don't use this pragma

The code:

```
use strict;
use v5.10;
use Data::Dumper;
# if I comment this line out, then the results print fine
use utf8;

my $s = {
    'data' => 'The size is 200 μg'
};

say Dumper( $s );
```

Results without `use utf8`:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'data' => 'The size is 200 μg'
        };
```

Results WITH using `use utf8`:

```
$VAR1 = {
          'data' => "The size is 200 \x{3bc}g"
        };
```

Thanks for any insights

Comment: Is your file encoded in utf-8? Have you opened your output handle for utf-8?

Comment: Yes it was encoded in UTF. I was encoding and decoding through JSON::XS and somewhere the encoding got lost. However, the use of `Encode::encode` as pointed out in the accepted answer helped keep things consistent

Comment: Note that with JSON and similar modules, `encode_json` and `decode_json` translate between Perl structures with decoded characters, and a JSON string in UTF-8 encoded bytes. This is almost always the translation you want, but you have to make sure those bytes don't get encoded again to UTF-8 when you output them, or decoded when you read them before running `decode_json`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is not garbled, but a standard Data::Dumper escape by the default "Useqq" configuration option listed [here](https://perldoc.pl/Data::Dumper#Configuration-Variables-or-Methods). Data::Dumper is designed for debugging and so this option lets you see what exact characters are when they may not be printable.

Without `use utf8;`, your string actually contains the UTF-8 encoded bytes of that character rather than the character itself, since that is what the file contains. You can verify this by checking the length of the string. `use utf8;` causes the interpreter to decode the source code from UTF-8, including your literal string.

In order to print such characters, it needs to be encoded back to UTF-8 bytes. You can either do this directly:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
use Encode 'encode';
print encode 'UTF-8', 'The size is 200 μg';
```

Or you can set an encoding layer on STDOUT, so that all printed text will be encoded to UTF-8:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use utf8;
binmode *STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
print 'The size is 200 μg';
```

Encoding to UTF-8 for Data::Dumper debugging is generally unnecessary, because it will escape such characters for your view already.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! The part about `encode` and also testing the size helped me determine whether it was truly a UTF8 or not

Comment: `binmode *STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';` should be `BEGIN { binmode *STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)'; binmode *STDERR, ':encoding(UTF-8)'; }` (or just `use open ':std', ':encoding(UTF-8)';`, but that does a bit more).